# Flutter- How do I print selected value instead of the selected value's lengths?

Tags: flutter, dart

## Here is the code that I used

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:filter_list/filter_list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp();

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Filter List',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: FilterPage(),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  final String? name;
  final String? avatar;
  User({this.name, this.avatar});
}

class FilterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  FilterPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final List<User> userList = [
    User(name: "Jon", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "Ethel ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "Elyse ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "Nail  ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "Valarie ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "Lindsey ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "Emelyan ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "Carolina ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "Catherine ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "Stepanida  ", avatar: ""),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Filter List Widget Example "),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FilterListWidget<User>(
          listData: userList,
          hideHeaderText: true,
          onApplyButtonClick: (list) {
            if (list != null) {
              print("Selected items count: ${list.length}");
            }
          },
          choiceChipLabel: (item) {
            /// Used to print text on chip
            return item!.name;
          },
          validateSelectedItem: (list, val) {
            ///  identify if item is selected or not
            return list!.contains(val);
          },
          onItemSearch: (list, text) {
            /// When text change in search text field then return list containing that text value
            ///
            ///Check if list has value which matchs to text
            if (list!.any((element) =>
                element.name!.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()))) {
              /// return list which contains matches
              return list
                  .where((element) =>
                  element.name!.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()))
                  .toList();
            }
            else{
              return [];
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So is there any way to change instead of printing the lengths, but I want to print the value in the selected list for example if I select "Ethel" and "Jon", I need it to print exactly the names. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Just try removing the length method on it. i.e print("Selected items count:"+ list);

Comment: when I try to do that I got this error messages "The argument type 'List<User>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. "

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the supposed answer. You can try this:

```
if (list != null) {
    list.map((value) {
      print("name: ${value.name}");
    }
} else {
      print("List is null");
}
```

Comment: it doesn't have any error but, it still won't print the value out.

Comment: can you check if your list is null or not? that may be the issue

Comment: final List<User> userList = [
    User(name: "PRO-101", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "PRO-102 ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "PRO-103 ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "PRO-104 ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "PRO-105 ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "PRO-106 ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "PRO-107 ", avatar: ""),
    User(name: "PRO-108 ", avatar: ""),
  ];
that is the list that I already defined.

Comment: No,  i mean to say try to check if the condition `list!=null` is true or not.

Comment: Ohh, how do I check that by the way?

Comment: check my updated answer if you see `List is null` on the log then your list is not being passed

Comment: I tried it and it just doesn't print any value out

Answer (score 0):

First, why do not use `print(list)`? In this case do not forget to override the `toString()` method.

```dart
String toString() => 'User (name: $name)';
```

Second, you may create a mapped list of user names and print it.

```dart
final selectedItems = list.map((user) => user.name).toList();
print(selectedItems);
```